# Access App key data from class libraries in .NET Core / ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

To access App Keys in a class library, do we need to do the following code in every class library and class where we need to access a AppKey?

```
public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
```

This is what I found in [Microsoft docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#using-the-built-in-sources), but this looks very redundant.

Startup class in a project as below

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

        public Startup()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddEntityFramework().AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:MyDb:ConnectionString"]));
        }
    }
```

Then how should I inject this "**IConfigurationRoot**" in each class of a project. And do I have to repeat this Startup class in each class Library? Why is this not part of .NET Core Framework?

Comment: Dude! someone must be really crazy to down-vote question with out even being qualified to have an account in SO, Who ever down voted this question, if you don't know .NET, find a tutor to teach you .NET in 30 days, just don't irritate me. And that DB don't even have quality of commenting why he/she is doing this BS act. This is very Annoying. SO team should really do some thing about these kind of acts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the principle of Information Hiding in Object-Oriented Programming, most classes should not need to have access to your application configuration. Only your main application class should need to directly have access to this information. Your class libraries should expose properties and methods to alter their behavior based on whatever criteria their callers deem necessary, and your application should use its configuration to set the right properties.

For example, a DateBox shouldn't need to know how timezone information is stored in your application configuration file - all it needs to know is that it has a DateBox.TimeZone property that it can check at runtime to see what timezone it is in.

Comment: If I get you correctly, are you saying I should not try to access AppKeys from any class Libraries rather I should pass values as Params from my Main Project (like Web site)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. When you encounter something like that that makes you feel like your code is awkward, step back and consider how the creators of the functionality you are using might have envisioned its use. It is very easy, especially when you are relatively new to OOP, to want to shortcut good design patterns and expose your data anywhere and everywhere. It can come back and hurt you later when you find out that your dependencies are so tight that changing anything has become a nightmare.

Comment: One way that this can help is if you want to create more generic class libraries that will work with Web Forms applications, MVC applications, Windows Forms applications, and/or console applications. Most libraries shouldn't care where they are, and shouldn't have to deal with the fact that configuration information may be stored in different places for different kinds of apps.

Comment: The possible way to avoid dependency of IOptions is to use extension TConfig ConfigurePOCO<TConfig>(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration), as suggested in https://www.strathweb.com/2016/09/strongly-typed-configuration-in-asp-net-core-without-ioptionst/

Comment: It's maybe semantics but the access to the configuration is still maintained by the application. The only thing that is communicated via the options are it's values how and when to use them is up to the object.

Answer (score 9):

The recommended way is to use the [options pattern](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#using-options-and-configuration-objects), provided by Microsoft and used heavily in ASP.NET Core.

Basically you create a strong typed class and configure it in the `Startup.cs` class.

```
public class MySettings 
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

and initialize it in the `Startup` class.

```
// load it directly from the appsettings.json "mysettings" section
services.Configure<MySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("mysettings"));

// do it manually
services.Configure<MySettings>(new MySettings 
{
    Value1 = "Some Value",
    Value2 = Configuration["somevalue:from:appsettings"]
});
```

then inject these options everywhere you need it.

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly MySettings settings;

    public MyService(IOptions<MySettings> mysettings) 
    {
        this.settings = mySettings.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's nothing but repeating this code in every class i need to access mySettings? isn't that a redundant work?

Comment: No, you only have **one single**  Startup.cs class: In your web application and nowhere else! In class libraries and all other services you only inject `IOptions<MySettings> mysettings`  into the class. And no it's not redundant, because you only read/instantiate it once and pass it around everywhere (you let the new built-in Dependency Injection Container do the work). Class libraries should **never** have a `Startup.cs`

Comment: Is this the only way .NET Core works? By injecting IOptions in each class where I need to access a Setting?

Comment: That's one of the reasons (ASP).NET Core ships with a built-in DI container and the `IOptions<T>` pattern was introduced. It is used in every of the ASP.NET Core libraries to pass configuration, just hidden behind the extensions methods like `services.AddMvc( options => ...)` https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/DependencyInjection/MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L187. You don't have to use it, but it's easier and works well with the idea of dependency injection. Fighting against it just may make stuff harder/more complicated

Comment: You could also encapsulate `IConfigurationRoot` into a service or simply register it with the DI system and inject it everywhere, but it's bad practice because you let infrastructure leak into your services, which will make unit tests just more complicated

Comment: Did you ever find a way around this? When I include `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions` in my library via NuGet it tries to include every package under the sun. It also seems to defeat the purpose of retiring `ConfigurationManager` a little - even though I register my settings class with the container, I have to include an external library in my project to use it. WHY? I went with the manual registration which allows me to use my settings class in my external library without `IOptions`, but it's frustrating to say the least. /rant

Comment: @AaronNewton: Well, like I said, injecting `IConfigurationRoot` or directly reading the config file from library is quite a bad practices, because you put infrastructure concerns into your library. The configuration (and hence `IConfiugrationRoot` should only be referenced in the main application, not in class libraries. You should only inject `IOptions<T>` (which is `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` package) into your class libraries and read/initialize/configure this options in your applications `Startup` class

Comment: Hello Tseng. My point is regarding `IOptions<T>`. If I register `MyCustomConfiguration`, I should just be able to use `MyCustomConfiguration` in my library. I can inject `MyCustomConfiguration` directly if I register it using the "do it manually" method above, but this is unsatisfying if I have a large number of settings. I counted - if I try to include `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` via NuGet it tries to include 37 packages in my library. This seems like a rediculous amount of bloat. Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding something...

Comment: @AaronNewton: `Micrsofot.Extensions.Options` only has two dependencies: `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` (no other dependencies) and `Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives` (also no dependencies). Everything else it requires is the runtime, which is implicit in former class libraries (because runtime was required to be installed on the target system). The difference is just, that .NET Core mustn't be preinstalled (if using self-contained apps).

Comment: `NETStandard.Library` is a meta package which references all common used packages for .NET Core runtime kind of a equivalent of targeting .NET 4.5 oder .NET 4.0 or .NET 2.0 in former class libraries. The number of packages is irrelevant, because .NET Core is modular and now distributed via NuGet package, which the legacy .NET Framework wasn't. With that argument, every legacy Class library would pull 100s of dependencies, because it reference the whole runtime ;)

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I'm going to go ahead and write a utility to register a class directly from the appSettings.config as even the reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` is a bit off-putting. I feel pretty strongly that the external library should have no dependencies of any sort relating to the DI container - this defeats the purpose of DI and I'm struggling to comprehend why Microsoft have done down this route.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150178/ioptions-injection/41151115#41151115 Of course nothing prevents you from injecting typed classes (`T`) rather than `IOptions<T>` into your services, but then you will need to register the typed classes yourself (in a separate class which references `Microsoft.Extensions.DependecyInjection.Abstractions`, but you loose certain aspects of the options pattern, like updating the options value when someone edits the appsettings.json. With options pattern, this is supported out of the box

Comment: Thank you Tseng. Like I said, I will wire up a utility to read all settings out of a configuration section, something like `services.AddSingleton<T>((_) => Utility.GetObjectPopulatedByAppSettingsSection<T>("SectionName"))`.