# Why is an ASP.NET-Core app 'Configuration/AppSettings' POCO passed around as IOptions<T> instead of just T?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

With .NET-Core apps the [configuration data read from some file/environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration) is loaded into an `IConfigurationRoot` instance. But I keep seeing examples that show that the injected instance is an `IOptions<T>` .. not an `IConfigurationRoot`.

- Why `IOptions`?
- What is the advantage of this class instead of just having my own `AppSettings` POCO?
- Do I need to do it this way? Is there another way?

For example..

```
public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                                            .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", true, true)
                                            .AddJsonFile($"appSettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
                                            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Register the IConfiguration instance which MyOptions binds against.
    services.Configure<AppConfiguration>(Configuration);

    // <snip other stuff>
}

public AccountController(IOptions<AppConfiguration> appConfiguration)
{
    // do stuff with appConfiguration here.
}
```

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41151115/455493) on this question. Technically you can't do w/o,  but you won't be able to update it when the appsettings.json gets changed

Comment: In my opinion, `IOptions<T>` have some disanvantages so we use pure POCOs as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43679665/5112433