# What should be passed for a connection?

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm working on a .NET Core library that's going to interface with a data source. It seems best to use the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#using-options-and-configuration-objects) to set up the library, but I'm not sure what type I should expect:

- (Connection) String - Then I need to figure out what I'm connecting to.
- DbContext - Seems specific to Entity Framework.
- DbConnection - I can't open and close at will if it's shared elsewhere.
- ??? - The best option.

**What is the best option?** I'm using the built in DI.

Answer (score 0):

At first, a little bit [theory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration):

> The configuration API provides a way of configuring an app based on a list of name-value pairs that can be read at runtime from multiple sources.
>
> Each configuration value maps to a string key.
>
> There’s built-in binding support to deserialize settings into a custom **POCO** object (a simple .NET class with properties).
>
> The options pattern uses custom options classes to represent a group of related settings. 
>   The options class must be non-abstract with a public parameterless constructor.

Now let's go back to your case:

- It doesn't matter, what class you use for settings storage, it is a wrapper around **list** of name-value pairs, retrieved from one of the setting sources. Moreover, it is possible to simply read the specific value from settings storage by key.
- Option class is a container for grouping related settings, where class property relates to Key by name. And this class must be POCO => has public properties, public parameterless constructor, etc. Classes like `DbContext`, `DbConnection` are not [POCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) classes.
- Any connection string (CS) can be stored as a string. You may check this using https://www.connectionstrings.com. So CS can be represented just as one key-value pair in your settings source. From the other hand, CS is also a set of key-value pairs (name of parameter = value) and could be split into separate parts. For example, simple CS to SQL Server has next template:

  ```
  Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword;
  ```

  that could be represented/stored in class like the following:

  ```
  public class ConnectionString
  {
      public string Server {get;set;}
      public string Database {get;set;}
      ...
  }
  ```

Comment: I think you missed that it's a library. The library does not have control over the consuming app's configuration. [An options class seems to be the recommended solution to for setting a library up.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38573042/1680677) Such a class is not limited to just string values like the configuration API is.