# IConfiguration does not contain a definition for GetValue

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, asp.net-core-2.2

After moving a class through projects, one of the `IConfiguration` methods, `GetValue<T>`, stopped working. The usage is like this:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace Company.Project.Services
{
    public class MyService
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public string BaseUri => _configuration.GetValue<string>("ApiSettings:ApiName:Uri") + "/";

        public MyService(
            IConfiguration configuration
        )
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 437, accepted):

Just install `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder` and the method will be available.

The reason is that `GetValue<T>` is an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.getvalue?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and does not exist directly in the `IConfiguration` interface.

Answer (score 47):

The top answer is the most appropriate here. However another option is to get the value as a string by passing in the key.

```
public string BaseUri => _configuration["ApiSettings:ApiName:Uri"] + "/";
```

Comment: This does not answers the question, because it specifically asks for how to fix that method. Although this is a good alternative for the initial approach, thanks.

Comment: Hey Jordan. Just wanted to thank you for posting this. Even though your reply may not directly answer the question, it does provide a decent alternative. I came here from google and I am now considering your way of retrieving settings. So I would consider your answer a valuable addition to this thread. Thanks mate :)

Comment: The advantage of this version is that it requires one less dependency. So it's my default choice for simple things like console applications.

Comment: Yeah, I actually think this approach is better than my initial one.  Just be aware of .NET versions and compatibility.