# Is there a way to access appsettings.json config without needing a constructor in the class I a trying to access it from

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a model class modeled after what I am trying to access in appsettings and in startup I have

```
 services.Configure<User>(Configuration.GetSection("Settings"));
```

my question is how can I access it in another class without needing DI or to have a constructor for that class, the reason I ask is because I already have a constructor

Comment: That's a form of the Service Locator Anti-pattern.  If you have a dependency, pass it in as a parameter via the constructor.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772001/access-to-configuration-without-dependency-injection ?