# What is the recommended pattern for .NET standard libraries using appsettings and IOptions interface?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm struggling to come up with the right design for a networking library I'm making. The library is written as a .NET standard project, and it requires configuration via `IOptions` (expecting some executable to supply these dependencies)

I was reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38573042/1343005) which is a guideline I've been following. Yet, my confusion is to how some application should use the library.

For example, I have a class named `Packet.cs` which needs some configuration.

```
public class Packet {
    public Packet(int maxSize) {
         ...
    }
}
```

Let's assume that `maxSize` is something that is configurable through `appsettings.js`. I write another class named `NetworkService.cs` which takes `IOptions` as such:

```
public class NetworkService {
    public NetworkService(IOptions<Settings> settings) {
         // save the settings
    }

    public Packet NewPacket() {
        return new Packet(settings.maxSize);
    }
}
```

Now, at this point, am I to assume that anything that wants to use my library must go through `NetworkService` because it's the only class that has settings? Is this the recommended design that I just have one interface to the entire library and all calls must go through it?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what the problem would be with this approach. Can you add some examples to show what you don't like about it?

Comment: I guess you are looking for Singleton pattern

Comment: No - anything that wants to use your library needs to include the Options library and include IOptions<Settings> in their class constructor just like you have in your NetworkService constructor. I would also add to your Network library a ServiceCollectionExtensions class with a method called ConfigureNetworking() or whatever you are calling your library - there you will bind your Settings object to the Configuration ==> services.Configure<Settings>(Configuration.GetSection("YourNetworkSettingsSection"))

Comment: Just to be complete - to add to my previous comment - the application Startup.ConfigureServices should call your ConfigureNetworking() method (e.g. services.ConfigureNetworking(Configuration).

Comment: @mdebeus Thanks for the point. I think you are referring to asp.net? I am writing a .NET standard library which doesn't include a `Startup` class. However, I did write one similar that basically works as you mentioned in your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking whether you have to use `NetworkService` to create `Packet` object, then the answer is yes, it's actually an implementation of Factory pattern.